# Deleting all dynamic DNS records from AD-Integrated DNS server? What can go wrong?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp, domain-controller

[1 Forest, 1 Domain, 2 DCs and nothing more - nothing special]

Is it OK, to remove all dynamic records from DNS.
If I decide to do so, should I do the same on the second Domain Controller?

Beside one result - that those records would not be available until they reappear
via one of ways dynamic DNS updates work.. I don't see any other consequences.

Let's say all the hosts have DHCP reservation and all things needed for their DNS records to be created or updated dynamically and automatically configured properly. And all of them are shut down.

1. I delete all non-static records.
2. I power on all hosts

Am I right thinking that they just reappear in DNS zone after that process?

Thank You!

P.S. The main goal is to clean up stale DNS records (one time only, and then configure proper aging and scavenging)

Comment: `they just reappear in DNS zone after that process?` Yes they will.

Comment: **The main goal is to clean up stale DNS records (one time only, and then configure proper aging and scavenging)** - enable scavenging and aging and then do this. Yes, the dynamically registered records will repopulate.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thank You for clarification, I think it answers my question. "enable scavenging and aging and then do this" - Noticed.